# Doubt over the proof of Cauchy Schwarz inequaity

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I am reading the following proof of Cauchy Schwarz inequality.

**Statement:** Let $V$ be an inner product space and $u, v \in V$. Then $|\langle u, v\rangle |\le \|u\| \|v\|$.

Proof of the above inequality goes as follows:

**Proof:** If $u$ or $v$ is zero then equality holds. So assuming that $u$ and $v$ are non zero.

Now consider the inner product $\langle v - \lambda u, v -\lambda u\rangle ~\geq 0$, where $\lambda = \frac{\langle v, u\rangle}{\langle u, u\rangle} = \frac{\overline{\langle u, v\rangle }}{\|u\|^2}$. And after that an easy proof is given. I have also attached the complete proof of this inequality. [image]

I am confused why this particular value of $\lambda$ is chosen? Why $\lambda$ is not an arbitrary scalar?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Calculus. The function $t\mapsto (u-tv, u-tv)$ is minimized when $t$ is that particular value.

Comment: @Bryan Thank you for the comment. Could you tell me why e want to minimize this function?  I want to know connection between your statement and Cauchy-Schwarz inequality? You can write as an answer.